# Php detail view codes nothing show product on detail.php page niether error

Tags: php

Today I created a PHP detail view page for products but detail view codes nothing show product on detail.php page neither error. [1 id int(20)]primary  AUTO_INCREMENT  [2  product_cat int(20)][3 cat_id int(20)][4file            varchar(100)latin1_swedish_ci
        5   product_title   text    latin1_swedish_ci
        6   product_price   int(10)         No  None
        7   product_desc

```
<?php 
        if(!isset($_GET['pro_id'])){
            $id = $_GET['pro_id'];

  $get_pro = "select * from newproduct where pro_id='$id'";

  $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);

  while ($row_pro=mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){

      $pro_id = $row_pro['id'];
      $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
      $pro_desc = $row_pro['product_desc'];
      $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
      $pro_image = $row_pro['file'];


      echo "
      <div class='probox8'>
      <div class='item89'>
      <h3 style='text-align:center;'>$pro_title</h3>

        <img src='admin_area/uploads/$pro_image' width='400' height='500' />
        <p style='margin-top:10px; margin-left:5px;'><b>Price:  </b>  $pro_price <b> SAR</b></p>
        <div style='padding:5px;'>

        <a href='index.php?add_cart=$pro_id' style='float:right;'><button >Add to Cart</button></a>
     </div>
     </div>
    </div>";
       }
      }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

$get_pro = "select * from newproduct where id='$id'";

there is no prod_id column  in database table

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shown us does not initialize the database connection ($con).

> if(!isset($_GET['pro_id'])){

So if you **don't** have a value for $_GET['pro_id'], then use it in a query?

> $get_pro = "select * from newproduct where pro_id='$id'";

This is vulnerable to SQL injection

There is no error checking - you should be checking for errors after each mysqli call.

> $pro_id = $row_pro['id'];

Why? You can do this:

```
print "<a href='index.php?add_cart=$row_pro[pro_id]' style='float:right;'><button >Add to Cart</button></a>\n"
```